# How to make app's style take higher priority than React Component that imports its own stylesheet?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a Standalone (Reusable) `CustomButton` component that imports its own stylesheet (`CustomButton.css`). I would like to apply a style to it using className through props, while putting the className styling in my own `App.css`.

The following are simplified examples of my code.

CustomButton.js:

```
import "CustomButton.css";

export default function CustomButton({className=null, children}) {
    return (
        <button className={"custom-button" + (className? " " + className: ""}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
};
```

CustomButton.css

```
.custom-button {
    background: green;
}
```

App.js:

```
import "./App.css"
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton";


export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <CustomButton className="app-button">This is app button</CustomButton>
        </div>
    )
};
```

App.css

```
.app-button {
    background: red;
}
```

With the following points in mind:

1. Without changing the order of the imports
2. Not allowing my App to modify the button through .class `custom-button` (simply because let us say the App doesn't know).
3. Without using `!important`
4. Without using inline styling.
5. Specificity doesn't work here. (I guess)
6. Without breaking **encapsulation** of `CustomButton` component and modifying `CustomButton.css`.

What could be happening now:

The `App.js` imports the the `App.css` first before importing the `CustomButton`. That's why when I add the className to the `CustomButton` component, the `CustomButton.css` will still win as according to order of appearance, it came last.

I thank you in advance for any opinions and answers you have.

What I want to happen:

- Make the button's background red.

What I was able to do:

- Enclosed the CustomButton.css rules in `@layer custom`. This `@layer` enclosed the CustomButton's styling rules into a named layer, which gave it the lowest priority as there were no other layers declared in my app. I don't know if I'm on the right path here.

Reason why I think this would not work for me:

- This solved it pretty much but I think this is going to break encapsulation. Using layer in a Standalone React Component, will require the App to know more about the Component. Especially the name of the layer that the CustomButton has.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is, in your CustomButton.jsx I would only apply the .custom-button className if you haven’t defined one as a prop.

This would look like:

```
className={className ? className : “custom-button”}
```

Comment: That is right Jesse if I want to override all custom styling I have in `CustomButton`. But say I wanted to change just the background color, what I would like to do is add a `bg-red` with `background: red;` in my App.css, and write it onto the CustomButton's className wherever I use it. It's like I want to keep 95% of custom styling, but override just one, without using !important. But I may consider your answer, it may just be the path I needed to try.

Comment: I’ll have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline style prop](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp) for additional styling in your component

Comment: Sorry @axjrl . _4. Without using inline styling_ , I'm not saying your answer is wrong but I'm just avoiding those points I've mentioned. I thought of these too. But using inline style is not my choice now. Thank you.